# JNI sources in the APK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-ndk-r4

I have an Android project with an NDK/JNI library in Eclipse Ganymede. Inexplicably, the bin folder contains a copy of all my C++ sources from the jni folder. So does the APK, if you rename it to ZIP and examine. If I delete those files from bin, then clean and rebuild, they're there again. What going on, please? I have no intention of distributing the sources along with the app.

Comment: If that's really the sources (not the assembled object files or dependencies lists, which is normal), than there is something wrong with your Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda resolved. For some reason, jni was listed in project properties under "Java build path". Once I've removed that, it was fine. No sure how did this condition come to be.